# Как можно создать SQL запросы с JOIN и без JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно создать SQL запросы с  JOIN и без JOIN.
Нужно вывести все записи из QUESTIONS, при условии (question_status = "approved") и если (question_user_id_from НЕ РАВНО NULL AND question_user_id_from = user_id) или (question_user_id_from РАВНО NULL AND question_user_id_from = user_id)

```
-------------------------------------------
QUESTIONS
-------------------------------------------
| question_status | question_user_id_from |
-------------------------------------------
| approved        | 111111                |
-------------------------------------------
| approved        | 111111                |
-------------------------------------------
| approved        | NULL                  |
-------------------------------------------

-------------
USERS
-------------
| user_id   |
-------------
| 111111    | 
-------------
```

Сделал подобный запрос, как описал в условии, начало выводить по 8 одинаковых результатов у кого question_user_id_from = NULL, при этом у кого question_user_id_from != NULL - вывело все записи. Вопрос, в том как сделать так чтобы выбирало в одному условии и в другом условии, при этом выводил и те и другие результаты.

**UPDATE:** Остановился на этом запросе, но он выводит очень много раз информацию где question_user_id_from = NULL (а надо выводить по одной записи), в зависимости от количества строк в таблице USERS.

> (SELECT * FROM questions,users WHERE questions.question_status =
>   "approved" AND questions.question_user_id_from IS NULL) UNION (SELECT
>   * FROM questions,users WHERE questions.question_status = "approved" AND questions.question_user_id_from = users.user_id)

Comment: `(question_user_id_from НЕ РАВНО NULL AND question_user_id_from = user_id) или (question_user_id_from РАВНО NULL AND question_user_id_from = user_id)` смысл этих условий, ибо в любом случае оно сработает, по факту оставьте `(question_status = "approved")`. Добавьте в вопрос все запросы которые вы пробовали.

Comment: `(question_user_id_from РАВНО NULL AND question_user_id_from = user_id)` Значение поля не может ОДНОВРЕМЕННО и быть Null, и быть равным некоему значению. Это условие всё целиком можно выбросить как вечно ложное. `(question_user_id_from НЕ РАВНО NULL AND question_user_id_from = user_id)` Второе условие может быть истинно только когда первое истинно. Соответственно первое условие можно выбросить, оставив только `(question_user_id_from = user_id)`. После этого останется только `(question_status = "approved" AND question_user_id_from = user_id)`. Пригодно и для INNER JOIN, и для картезианки...

Answer (score 2):

Допустим есть две таблицы. table1 и table2.

1. Как соеденить таблицы без join

   ```
   select * from table1, table2  // Просто соеденить без условий

   select * from table1, table2 where table2.parent_id = table1.id
       // Соединить при вхождении одной таблицы в другую
   ```
2. Как соединить таблицы используя join

   ```
   select * from table1 
       /*left right inner*/ join table2 on table2.parent_id = table1.id

   select * from table1 cross join table2
   ```
3. Как соединить используя union

   ```
   select id from table1 /*where условие 1*/
   union select parent_id from table2 /*where условие 2*/
   ```

   если table1 = table2 то можно переписать это в один select так

   ```
   select * from table1 where (/*условие1*/ id = 1)  or  (/*условие2*/ id = 2)
   ```

Comment: По большому счёту в вашем случае `union` = `or`. Перепишите без union, с использованием or, и если буду проблемы - поставьте distinct.